# how to change cstring to unicode

Tags: c++, char

i am now working in VC++ 6. and I have a cstring content. How to change to content to unicode ?
for exmaple, I have a defined

```
CString strName;
```

`strName` Have some content in it(may some chinese character in it).

and also defined:

```
Unicode* chinese_character;
```

How to transfer the content of `strName` into the `chinese_character`?

Note that I am working in VC++ 6.

Thanks.

Comment: What is a `Unicode`? That's not a type that I'm aware of.

Comment: I understand as unsigned short

Comment: @user1279988: In VC6, that would typically be called `WCHAR*`.

Answer (score 0):

After googling I find a useful function as mbstowcs() which is used to convert multibyte string to wide-character string.

Below the example for this.

```
{
    wchar_t buf[255];
    mbstowcs(buf,(const char*)name,name.GetLength()+1);

    BYTE bytes[255];
    size_t length = wcslen(buf);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      bytes[i*2] = buf[i] >> 8;
      bytes[i*2+1] = buf[i] & 0xFF;
    }
  }
```